# Spurious characters when populating the quickfix windows with ls command in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying a simple custom command in Vim to populate the quickfix window with external commands. Currently just trying `ls` to get used to the tool. However when I run `:cexpr system("ls") | copen` I get annoying extra characters:

```
|| file1
|| file2
```

By the way, this does no "honour" the PWD, it just lists the home directory. Both errors might be related?

What is putting these extra characters in the quickfix list?

Comment: Those characters have been part of the quickfix window since forever so I wonder how they can be considered "spurious"? If you want to populate the quickfix window, you… want those characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim itself puts the pipes there. They're the separators for filename and line number, respectively, as parsed by the `errorformat` option. This is documented in `:help quickfix-window-function`:

> The default format for the lines displayed in the quickfix window and location
> list window is:
> `<filename>|<lnum> col <col>|<text>`

This can easily be demonstrated by running a command that is matched by the default `errorformat`:

```
:cexpr system("echo foo.py:123:OMG an error")
```

which will result in the following quickfix entry:

```
foo.py|123| OMG an error
```

So whatever you intend to do with your quickfix evaluation, you should set the `errorformat` option accordingly as described in `:help errorformat` and `:help 'errorformat'`. For a simplistic example using `ls`, it may be hard to come up with an `errorformat` that makes much sense.

I don't know how to get rid of the two pipes. I'd advise to go with them and use them. If you really want a quickfix list without a filename and a line number, you may not want quickfix in the first place. Consider using another kind of (temporary) buffer instead. See `:help 'buftype'` and `:help special-buffers` for more information.

You may also find `:help write-compiler-plugin` helpful. The idea is to define a `makeprg` (really, this can be any program that produces an output) together with an `errorformat` that can parse this output.

I could not reproduce any issues with the working directory.

Comment: It's true that maybe I'm using the wrong tool. I don't really need the quickfix, I just thought it's the way to have a temporal buffer shown read only info. What ohter kind of temporary buffer you mean? Overall, I want to have a way to visualise and query the queue in my system (which uses SLURM) without leaving Vim.

Comment: For instance, the buffer that uses fugitive when you type `:G`. How could I do something alike?

Comment: I edited my answer with some relevant help sections. Fugitive's `:G` uses `buftype=nowrite` and that might also work for you. I'm afraid I cannot say much about SLURM, you might ask a new question that's more about your problem and less about what you think the solution might be. Seems we were bitten by that old XY problem.